# How to prevent pH-sensor from maxing out, when pump is turned on?

Tags: sensor, signal, interference, ph

I am a bioproces engineer currently working with setting up a pH control system in a bioreactor (basically a large vessel filled with water). Hence, my electronics knowledge is quite limited.

Initially, the setup worked just fine. 
However, after installing a recirculation pump, we are having trouble with the readouts from the pH-sensor.

I have tried my best (with only a smartphone available) to depict the setup below:
[image: Setup]

The problem is, that when the pump is turned on, the readouts from the sensor 'maxes out'.

Observations:

- When the pump is turned off, the sensor readings are just fine, when compared to an external reference.
- As soon as the pump is turned on, the sensor-readings maxes out. However, when the pump is turned off again, the readings fall back to normal.
- If the same probe is inserted into a handheld, battery-powered device, the readings are UNAFFECTED by the state of the pump.
- It is not a matter of mixing caused by the pump or a real change in pH-value. (checked by sampling the fluid with a chemical analysis).

So this must be caused by the electronics, but I have no idea why, and how to prevent it.

For reference, the principle behind a pH-sensor is to measure the electrical potential between an pH-electrode which is in contact with the liquid, and an isolated reference electrode (both encapsulated in the same probe). 
Hence, any parameters that would affect this potential would also affect the readings.

What am I missing? 
I hope you guys can help!

Comment: Sounds like the pump has imperfect insulation and some 60Hz current flows up the pipe from the pump impellor to the ph sensor. If I recall, ph sensors are very high resistance (thin glass shell) and only nanoAmps are adequate to provide the sensed current. So,yes, use isolated power for the sensor.

Comment: Certainly not the worst drawing I have seen uploaded here. For future reference, there's a schematic editor in the system as well. Top left when entering information. In stead of high-isolation supplies you could also test whether the pump housing is strongly grounded (direct wire to metal parts). If not, a solution may be, if the setup is guaranteed to be at a grounded outlet (for safety reasons with some supplies) to actively connect power ground to anything metal touching the water, as well as your system's 0V / GND wire on the 5V side. See what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely you have some form of ground loop.
The best way to get rid of this is to either use a high isolation power supply (230-5 VDC) or use a high isolation DC-DC convertor after you existing AC-DC power supply. Units such as [these](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/r/recom-power/dcdc-converters) have extreme isolation and should provide what you need at very low prices (< $20).

Comment: Thanks a lot! In terms of available space in the casings, I then think it would be better to use a single isolated power supply. Do you have have a link to where I can buy these as well? The results are quite limited, when Googling stuff like "high isolation power supply".

Comment: You could test out using an isolation transformer, these are relatively cheap ( https://www.amazon.com/Precision-1604A-Single-Isolation-Transformer/dp/B000LDLF3M/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1496207790&sr=8-3&keywords=isolation+transformer). This may be enough to work for you.